# Fix incorrect encoding on PDF file processed in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, encoding, utf-8

I'm working on a project where we were dealing with PDF files that were supposed to be imported from a different datasource, but we noticed that some of those PDFs are displayed as blank pages only. Like a file with 10 pages and all of them being empty.

After reviewing some of the older code doing this, I noticed that the process importing the blank PDFs was doing it like this:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient();
RestRequest request = RestRequest(path, Method.Get, DataFormat.Json);
//yup, this .Get is redundant because the verb was already specified on the request
var result = client.Get(request); 
string fileContent = result.Content;
byte[] fileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileContent);
```

And then proceeds to save the file with that byte array that came from encoding the file to UTF8.
As far as I understand, that's wrong. Files should be processed at bytes level and avoid any encoding before saving it, the encoding is for when you read it, but not to do it before saving it because you're now altering the file contents, causing that blank PDFs issue because now it ends up with illegible characters.

Now, the problem is that the original files are gone and there's no way to get them back, we need to get these "corrupted" files fixed, but I still can't figure out how to perform an inverse process to take those files, read them, remove the mess caused by that encoding and take them back to how they should originally be.
I already tried with the most obvious one, which is using the UTF8.GetDecoder() to try to decode the file contents, but without success.

Any idea of what could we do to get those files back to their original format? I like to be positive of this not being something that cannot be fixed and that I'm just not looking at the right place.

**Edit:** I also managed to take a random pdf that works, processed like this to see how much the content of the PDF file did change and the main change was how a lot of weird characters that can be seen in the original document, after getting them encoded, they became something similar to this ■ when opening it on Notepad.

**Edit 2:** I do know that getting the content as a string is wrong and that RestSharp has a RawBytes property that should have been used, so that nothing got ever encoded on the first place. This is not about how it should have been, since it's someone else's code from months ago that I already updated to do it the right way, but the problem is on the files it already imported months ago with that old approach and if there's any way to get them back by undoing the mess caused by processing it as a string, instead of bytes.

Comment: Your code example doesn't help. What does `getFileContent()` do? And the next line would not even compile but I assume you meant to use `GetBytes()`?

Comment: I do not think the Encoding is wrong.  The error is reading the file into a string.  You should replace the two statements with  byte[] fo;eButes = File.ReadAllBytes()

Comment: @Crowcoder The code is just to display what is the algorithm doing. GetFileContent just retrieves the file content as a string, that's all. It could either be as File.ReadAllText() or any other way and then proceeds to encode it to transform it into a byte array by encoding it (btw, I added the .GetBytes() that I was missing after the UTF8).

Comment: @jdweng I do completely agree with you. This should ideally be something completely managed at bytes level and that's how the other imports are doing it, but for some reason, the one who made that one decided to do it with strings, causing this issue

Comment: *"GetFileContent just retrieves the file content as a string, that's all."* - but which encoding does `GetFileContent` use while doing so? If it also assumed UTF-8, then that's where the file contents got damaged beyond repair (there are byte sequences that make no sense when interpreted as UTF-8 text; such sequences then usually are replaced by replacement characters which loses the original bytes). If it assumed a different encoding, use that different encoding, too, in your `fileBytes = ...` code line.

Comment: @EstebanCervantes :  I'm not disagreeing with you.  Just want to explain a little more about encoding.  When usuing encoding to convert to strings data can get changed.  UTF8 the changes only occur with the byte 0x80.  That is why I said the Encoding was correct.  Strings in c# are class object that contain one or two bytes and an internal property that indicates if a char is one or two bytes.  When converting a pdf to string and then back to bytes can cause issues if the pdf contains unicode (two byte characters),  The unicode character could get split and the 0x80 would then get changed.

Comment: @mkl I added more details, since it seems like I was oversimplifying and making it harder for anyone trying to help on this. Thanks for the heads up! Since it just read it as ".Content" from the result of the HTTP request, ignoring the "ContentEncoding" property to decide what to do with it. I do understand that the right thing to do here was to actually take the value from the RawBytes property and work with that, but based on the latest comments, I'm starting to feel concerned about the possibility of that string manipulation affecting the bytes to a point beyond repair...

Comment: @jdweng Sorry if it did seem like I was discussing, I just wanted to clarify that in case it seemed like it was my decision to manipulate them like that :P
Also, thanks for the explanation. Actually that unicode part makes a lot of sense for some scenarios where the files don't even display empty pages, but just throw an error while opening the PDF, potentially meaning that it was a similar scenario to the one you described

Comment: @EstebanCervantes what you try to do is wrong to begin with. PDF isn't a text document and shouldn't be treated this way. *Some* parts of it may contain 7-bit ASCII but others can contain binary data like images. The binary parts may be compressed. Even if the API returns the file as a string (a *serious bug*), using UTF8 or any other random encoding won't produce the original file. Any byte combinations that have no equivalent in the encoding will be lost and replaced by `?`.

Comment: The only way decoding would work would be by luck - the API would have to use a codepage that allows all byte values (most codepages *don't* allow all byte values) and your code used that encoding. UTF8 *doesn't* allow all combinations. It's a **LOT** easier to return the PDF file as a proper file with the correct content type

Comment: *"Since it just read it as ".Content" from the result of the HTTP request..."* - `.Content` returns a `string`. Thus, it already is wrong to use it, you should access the result using a different method which returns a byte array (or a `MemoryStream` or something similar). If `result` does not offer such a method, use a different REST client API that does.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If I get it, this might not be as it exactly is, but just the general idea. When the UTF8 encoding comes into play, if the PDF has characters that UTF8 doesn't understand, like "☻♦♣" (just an example, not saying UTF8 doesn't understand those ones), it'll change them to something like "■■■" where the byte representation has been updated to match that, because it didn't had any other way to represent it. If you want to get it back, it doesn't know how to do it, because it didn't knew how to represent them on the first place, not allowing them to be recovered. Is that correct?